# How can fetch data from json through php?

Tags: php, json

I have a json context, i want some data from that json, My json is

```
{
"req_payload": "{\"config\": {\"action\": \"test\", \"user_id\": \"219096271813\", \"endpoint_url\": \"http:\/\/debasisa.testbase.info\/demo-push.php\", \"webhook_id\": \"430339\"}, \"api_url\": \"https:\/\/www.demo.com\/{api-endpoint-to-fetch-object-details}\/\"}"
}
{
"req_payload": "{\"config\": {\"action\": \"test\", \"user_id\": \"219096271813\", \"endpoint_url\": \"http:\/\/debasisa.testbase.info\/demo-push.php\", \"webhook_id\": \"430339\"}, \"api_url\": \"https:\/\/www.demo.com\/{api-endpoint-to-fetch-object-details}\/\"}"
}
```

I need **action** and **api_url** data from json. I try something and i get upto

```
 {"config": {"action": "test", "user_id": "219096271813", "endpoint_url": "http://debasisa.testbase.info/demo-push.php", "webhook_id": "430339"}, "api_url": "https://www.dem.com/{api-endpoint-to-fetch-object-details}/"}
```

But i have no idea, how to get action and api_url value from this content in PHP.

Comment: `json_decode` can help you.

Comment: Thanx@urfusion, I use json_decode, but i get  **{"config": {"action": "test", "user_id": "219096271813", "endpoint_url": "http://debasisa.testbase.info/demo-push.php", "webhook_id": "430339"}, "api_url": "https://www.dem.com/{api-endpoint-to-fetch-object-details}/"}**, how can i fetch **action** and **api_url**  from this content

Comment: @Debasish : check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$level1 = '{
"req_payload": "{\"config\": {\"action\": \"test\", \"user_id\": \"219096271813\", \"endpoint_url\": \"http:\/\/debasisa.testbase.info\/demo-push.php\", \"webhook_id\": \"430339\"}, \"api_url\": \"https:\/\/www.demo.com\/{api-endpoint-to-fetch-object-details}\/\"}"
}';
$data = json_decode($level1);
$newdata = json_decode($data->req_payload);
$action = $newdata->config->action;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = json_decode($input);
```

You can use `$output->req_payload->config->action` and `$outout->api_url` if your JSON is a single object. If it is an array, then you will have to iterate its elements. And if it is like the one you have shown in your question, then it is invalid JSON.